# Keypress working in chrome but not firefox

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, keypress

I am trying to prevent the user from entering anything but a number. It works in Chrome but not Firefox. I have gone through many solutions but no luck. I have used keydown, keypress, different events etc. Please help. If it helps this is all in a aspx file.

```
onkeypress="return myFunction(event);"

<script type="text/javascript">
    // Check if key press is a number
    function myFunction(evt) {
        var e = event || evt; // for trans-browser compatibility
        var charCode = e.which || e.keyCode;

        if (charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57)) {
            alert("Enter Numbers Only");
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Did you try using e.charCode? e= evt.which||evt.charCode||evt.keyCode;

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't understand this line

```
var e = event || evt; // for trans-browser compatibility
```

Where do you get event? This was throwing error in Firefox.

I modified the code and tested it with Chrome and Firefox. First the HTML with input

```
<input onkeypress="return validate(event);" />
```

and the function

```
// Check if key press is a number
function validate(e) 
{ 
    var charCode = e.which || e.keyCode;

    if (charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57)) 
    {
        alert("Enter Numbers Only");
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/bskqpgvy/2/

Comment: Great, select as valid answer and also credit @Jason for his contribution.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if part of the script wasn't included, but from what I can see the code provided above didn't work in any browser.

http://jsfiddle.net/e5d8txa2/

```
window.addEventListener("keypress", function(evt) {
    myFunction(evt);
});

// Check if key press is a number
function myFunction(evt) {
    var e = event || evt; // for trans-browser compatibility
    var charCode = e.which || e.keyCode;

    if (charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57)) {
        alert("Enter Numbers Only");
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

As an aside, if the field is typed only for numbers, in modern browsers you can use the "number" type in the input field. This should throw an visible error to the user when attempting to submit. Of course, you should also verify the field values in other ways as necessary.

Comment: Thanks for your contribution